# TSQL deadlock on select with XLOCK ROWLOCK

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Simple problem - I have 300k tasks in a SQL Server table and I want multiple processes to pick them one by one, process them and save the result.

And I'm getting deadlocks on both picking and saving from time to time.

I need to make sure that two processes won't pick the same task. So I'm using `XLOCK` and after task is taken I'm changing status from 1-Created to 2-Started and after it's processed to 3-Completed.

Also my tasks (`tblTasksSets`) is referenced one-to-one to `tblGeneralSets` (please don't ask ;)) and `tblGeneralSets` is referenced many-to-one  to `tblContainers`.

So I have two procedures one to update and select picked task:

```
DECLARE @SetIds AS TABLE(Id INT)    
-- Updating status
;WITH innerTable  AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 taskSets.* 
    FROM tblTasksSets taskSets WITH (XLOCK ROWLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN tblGeneralSets generalSets WITH(XLOCK ROWLOCK) ON generalSets.TaskSetId = taskSets.Id  
    WHERE generalSets.ContainerId = @ContainerId
      AND taskSets.ParameterSetStatusId = 1 --CREATED
) 
UPDATE innerTable 
SET ParameterSetStatusId = 2 -- STARTED
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @SetIds

-- Here are some unrelated updates on log history tables

-- And returning result
SELECT
    taskSets.*, containers.*
FROM 
    tblTasksSets taskSets
INNER JOIN 
    tblGeneralSets generalSets ON generalSets.TaskSetId = taskSets.Id
INNER JOIN 
    tblContainers containers ON containers.Id = generalSets.ContainerId
WHERE 
    taskSets.Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM @SetIds)
```

and second one to mark task as completed:

```
UPDATE tblTasksSets 
SET 
....
WHERE Id = @Id
```

Any ideas why I'm getting deadlocks? I just want one process to wait for another to finish his updates.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 53) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

At the time of the tests there were no other queries run on this db. Just 50 processes calling these two stored procedures every few seconds maybe

[sp_lock shows something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS6I2.png)

[Deadlock Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN1oH.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when you run `sp_lock` during that, you will see a single connection blocks a lot of rows when it only wants to block one. This would be due to the join and/or lack of proper indices. Even if that's not the case, the other connections will still have to wait to make sure the currently locked rows do not satisfy their `where`, so you will have zero concurrency.

Comment: You probably want an `update top (1) ... from ... with (rowlock, holdlock, readpast) where ... `. [The `readpast` hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table).

Comment: Can you post the deadlock graph? http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/gathering-deadlock-information-deadlock-graph

Comment: GSerg I was doing small research and found out that in some cases it can happen that two queries will pick up one item in this scenario, apparently update is not an atomic operation

Comment: You can generally avoid deadlock issues on update with updlock, check this article out for more information: http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/

Comment: Are you using transactions, and what is your isolation level?

Comment: using deafault transaction made it much worse so no I'm not using it.

Comment: @Shaulinator I've edite original post with Deadlock Graph
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN1oH.png

Answer (score 1):

There is a brute force way to serialize access to your resource. Using the built in locking of sql server you can queue access to your work with [SP_GETAPPLOCK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql). An example would be :

```
CREATE PROC MyCriticalWork(@MyParam INT)      
AS
    DECLARE @LockRequestResult INT = 0    
    DECLARE @MyTimeoutMiliseconds INT =5000--Wait only five seconds max then timeout

    BEGIN TRAN

    EXEC @LockRequestResult=SP_GETAPPLOCK 'MyCriticalWork','Exclusive','Transaction',@MyTimeoutMiliseconds
    IF(@LockRequestResult>=0)BEGIN

            /*
            DO YOUR CRITICAL READS AND WRITES HERE
            */

        COMMIT TRAN -- <--Releases the lock!
    END ELSE
        ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Ross Bush thanks I didn't know that feature. I'm still looking into other options provided by people commenting on my question but for sure I will use your approach as my last resort. Someone give that man some points ;) I can't due to being 1h old user.

Comment: This serializes all calls and makes sure there is no concurrency. I believe the OP's idea was that different connections can work simultaneously.

Comment: My main goal is to ensure that two connections will not pick up the same task to process. Solution provided by Ross actually ensures that but the disadvantage is that I would need to implement it in all places where I update critical table. I would rather have table-hint-based solution but if I don't find one I will use solution provided by Ross.

Comment: You might get a better answer over at http://dba.stackexchange.com. The general rule of thumb is that the deadlock victim sql server chooses is the transaction holding the least amount of resources with the assumption that it will be the easiest to rollback. If there are reads and writes in deadlock contention it will "almost" always be the read that is rolled back. You can mitigate having to retry transactions under dire circumstances in a high transaction environment by hinting with nolock, however, you better be sure it's ok if your read query comes back dirty in such a case.

Comment: @devops_granted [The `readpast` hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354664/tsql-deadlock-on-select-with-xlock-rowlock/43355339#comment73772905_43354664) specifically exists to support a queue of job items for different connections to claim. You begin the transaction, you lock one record by selecting it with `updlock, rowlock, readpast`, you do the work, you commit the transaction which releases the lock. You don't need a `status` field which you would update, and setting that field is generally useless because the record will be unavailable for reading anyway.